# Transforming non-normal data

Tags: normal-distribution

If the data for dependent variable is not normally  distributed and when the data is transformed the skewness becomes less than 1 but the Shapiro Wilk test says its not normally distributed so what other remedies are available?
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Why do you need your dependent variable to have a normal distribution? What analysis are you doing with it?

Comment: thanks for the reply.The h0= Male and female use SMS(Messaging) equally

Comment: That's the hypothesis, rather than the analysis. What did you plan to do? How is SMS(messaging) measured? Number of messages?

Comment: thanks for the reply.The h0= Male and female use SMS(Messaging) equally.dependent variable :SMS (likert scale:hourly=1,atleast once daily=2,every few days=3,weekly=4,donot use=5.dependent variable gender:male/female.Number of repsonses 415.male=350,female=75.

Comment: iwant to perform one way ANOVA on it .The DV isnt normally distributed.I tried transformation with LG but it only brought skewnes with in limitis <1.The Shapiro Wilk test says its not normally distributed.It also has outliers.Does this mean i can not run parametric test on it such as ANOVA and ihave to shift to non parametric test?

Answer (score 1):

1. About testing the DV for normality: -- For ANOVA, the DV on its own needn't be normally distributed. Within each group it should be reasonably close to normal (this is usually assessed by examining residuals after; typically combining the groups into one when dealing with residuals).

   A goodness of fit test doesn't really tell you whether you're reasonably close to normal.

   "Non-normal" doesn't imply you can't have a parametric model.
2. However, your DV is *ordinal categories*.

   Your problems run deeper than just "non-normal", since the difference between categories 2 and 1 is nothing like the difference between categories 5 and 4 -- you can't just treat that sort of variable as if it were an interval response.

   Many questions on site discuss analyses with ordinal DVs.